# Argument read from right to left

Tags: c, perl

I am learning how buffer overflows work and ran across something I do not understand.

I am trying to change a function pointer's address via buffer overflow with an argument passed into an executable that is run from a Perl script.  My question is, why does Perl seem to read my address argument from right to left?

Perl:

```
$arg = "AAAAAAAAAA"."\x40\x11\xc4";  //string with address to malicious test function
$cmd = "./bo_test ".$arg;
system($cmd);
```

The address entered is the exact address of this function when printed out.  However, in order to get the test function to be called via overflow I need to enter "\xc4\x11\x40" instead.

If I point right to the address in C it takes the input I would expect:

```
//call function based on address pointer_fn
desired_fn = ( void (*)())0x4011c4; //when run desired_fn runs the malicious test method
```

Can someone explain why Perl does this (or what I'm doing wrong to cause it)?

If it helps, I am using strcopy() to copy the argument and start the overflow in my exe.

Comment: Looks like you have a little endian system.

Comment: Are you running on a little endian machine or a big endian machine?

Comment: @Glenn, little endian (Intel Q8400).

Comment: hehehe, sounds like someone got a pearl problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have a string:

```
char* s = "\x40\x11\xc4";
```

If you have a integral type of size 3-bytes and you want treat the contents of the string as the 3-byte integer, you would use:

```
the_int_type* p = (the_int_type*)s;
```

In a little endian system, the value of `*p` will be:

```
0x40 + (0x11 >> 8) + (0xc4 >> 16)
```

In a big endian system, that will be:

```
(0x40 >> 16) + (0x11 >> 8) + 0xc4
```

Judging by the behavior you are describing, you have a little endian system.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I checked and do indeed have a little endian system.  Thank you for the clarification!